# How to store data (notes, assignees) to recurring events generated using RRULE

Tags: database-design, calendar, icalendar, rrule

I'm building a calendar application that allows users to create recurring events.

Instead of creating a new object in MongoDB for each recurring event, I am creating a single event object with a recurrence rule attached to it.

Then on the client I am 'expanding' the recurrence rule to create temporary objects for each recurrence of the event so they all display in the calendar.

That all works really well and prevents my DB from filling up with hundreds of objects any time an event recurs frequently. My question is: how can I then store data against each recurring event? For example, playing around with Google calendar I can create a recurring event and then add 'notes' to each recurrence. The notes can either be added to a single event or all events.

My thoughts so far are when a user wants to add 'notes', to add an EXDATE for the recurrence the user is editing, then create a new standalone event object for it.

I'm not sure if that's the best way to approach this though. Advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of iCalendar representation, the correct way to model such exception is to have it be part of the same event (same UID), with an additional RECURRENCE-ID parameter. You should not add an EXDATE:

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:XXX
DTSTART;TZID=zzz:20170401T090000
RRULE:FREQ=DAILY
...
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:XXX
RECURRENCE-ID;TZID=zzz:20170405T090000
DTSTART;TZID=zzz:20170405T090000
... 
END:VEVENT
```

Please note that the RECURRENCE-ID of the exception should always correspond to the datetime as calculated from the RRULE, while the DTSTART of the exception may differ (e.g. if on one instance you move the time of the event from 9 to 10, the RECURRENCE-ID will be T090000 while the DTSTART would have T100000.

See also https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5546#section-4.4.2